# Recovering volumes lost after docker-compose up

Tags: postgresql, docker

I run the command docker-compose up and the postgres container was recreated and all data lost. I had no named volume. Is there are a way of recovering the data?

Comment: If you are using the official postgres image, it has an unamed volume which you could find in /var/lib/docker/volumes/. You'll need to go through the folders there and see which is your postgres data folder. Then you can make a copy and mount it to /var/lib/postgresql/data of your container